# python find_all_next in beautifulsoup can't find a string

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, instagram

I'm trying to get a username from Instagram page. And I should use a part of data which I get after "data = soup.find_all('script') [3]"
It looks like this:

> Blockquote
>   (script type="text/javascript">window._sharedData = {"config":{"csrf_token":"hIuZDxW17bTXz5EDLY25ftqivOOrLEeZ","viewer":null,"viewerId":null},"supports_es6":false,"country_code":"RU","language_code":"en","locale":"en_US","entry_data":{"PostPage":[{"graphql":{"shortcode_media":{"__typename":"GraphImage","id":"1968747493659350883","shortcode":"BtSZWokAZdj","dimensions":{"height":640,"width":640},"gating_info":null,"media_preview":"ACoq5miitSxxIGTHPXPGcd8ZFAGXRXSSWypFsAAZ/lzjpn/Csm5sjAu7Ib8MUAUaKU0lABVq0lMUqsPUA/Q8VVpynBB9CKAOtuOFB9CD+uP5Gq19HuiOPTP5Ul1exhdgy7kdF7fU/wCGatJiRPqv5ZFIZybnP4UynOpUlT1HFNpiClDFeRSUUATLcSJ904+lPF5MvR2H41WooAc7lzuY5J702iigD//Z","display_url":"https://instagram.fhel3-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/68311f4b09669fd75609e9fcabbf1ae0/5D0517DE/t51.2885-15/e35/49907137_294327238101721_6745007497573009307_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fhel3-1.fna.fbcdn.net","display_resources":[{"src":"https://instagram.fhel3-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/68311f4b09669fd75609e9fcabbf1ae0/5D0517DE/t51.2885-15/e35/49907137_294327238101721_6745007497573009307_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fhel3-1.fna.fbcdn.net","config_width":640,"config_height":640},{"src":"https://instagram.fhel3-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/68311f4b09669fd75609e9fcabbf1ae0/5D0517DE/t51.2885-15/e35/49907137_294327238101721_6745007497573009307_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fhel3-1.fna.fbcdn.net","config_width":750,"config_height":750},{"src":"https://instagram.fhel3-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/68311f4b09669fd75609e9fcabbf1ae0/5D0517DE/t51.2885-15/e35/49907137_294327238101721_6745007497573009307_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fhel3-1.fna.fbcdn.net","config_width":1080,"config_height":1080}],"accessibility_caption":"Image may contain: one or more people and closeup","is_video":false,"should_log_client_event":false,"tracking_token":"eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjo1LCJwYXlsb2FkIjp7ImlzX2FuYWx5dGljc190cmFja2VkIjp0cnVlLCJ1dWlkIjoiN2Q1Yjg2NmY5OGIwNDVhNWIxMmRhNjEwZTA3NDY1MmYxOTY4NzQ3NDkzNjU5MzUwODgzIn0sInNpZ25hdHVyZSI6IiJ9","edge_media_to_tagged_user":{"edges":[]},"edge_media_to_caption":{"edges":[{"node":{"text":"\u2022\nScars show your story. \nYour pain. \nYour hate.\nYour sadness and despair. \nThey make you who you are, and one of a kind with every different mark. \nSome stay, some go.\nSome brighter, some lighter.\nSome bigger, some smaller.\nSome deeper, some one the surface. \nBut they are really all the same, you see?\nThey are all scars, just telling different points of our life, our story. \nOur souvenir throughout our whole life, that shows us how much we've grown. \nHow much we have overcome. How strong we've become.\nHow brave and courageous we've become from the hardest and darkest times of our life. \u2022\n\u2022\n\u2022\n\u2022\n#poem #cuts #selfharm #tatoo #dark #pain #sad #lonely #anxiety #depressed"}}]},"caption_is_edited":true,"has_ranked_comments":false,"edge_media_to_comment":{"count":1,"page_info":{"has_next_page":false,"end_cursor":null},"edges":[]},"comments_disabled":false,"taken_at_timestamp":1548913011,"edge_media_preview_like":{"count":17,"edges":[]},"edge_media_to_sponsor_user":{"edges":[]},"location":null,"viewer_has_liked":false,"viewer_has_saved":false,"viewer_has_saved_to_collection":false,"viewer_in_photo_of_you":false,"viewer_can_reshare":true,"owner":{"id":"10173498181","is_verified":false,"profile_pic_url":"https://instagram.fhel3-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/9a17134e8d0a36efec53f1da5cac1f38/5D14BC0F/t51.2885-19/s150x150/47690762_475199173011446_4764198224049209344_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fhel3-1.fna.fbcdn.net","username":"devils.*.tea.*","blocked_by_viewer":false,"followed_by_viewer":false,"full_name":"depressed\ud83e\udd40","has_blocked_viewer":false,"is_private":false,"is_unpublished":false,"requested_by_viewer":false}......

There is "username" part (at the end of blockquote). I think that it is a string, but I can't catch it. So it's not a string, but what is it? It is a class? Which method I should use to retreive the username "username":"devils.*.tea.*". Thank you in advance, if you can help.

```
....
req = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, "lxml")
data = soup.find_all('script') [3]
username = data.find_all_next(string="username")
print (username)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or, for those of us who don't like regex (nudge, nudge @QHarr :D), you can try this:

```
data = [your quote above]
data_list = data.split(",")
for i in data_list:
   if 'username' in i:
       print(i)
```

Output:

```
"username":"devils..tea."
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use regex

```
import re
data = '''
(script type="text/javascript">window._sharedData = {"config":{"csrf_token":"hIuZDxW17bTXz5EDLY25ftqivOOrLEeZ","viewer":null,"viewerId":null},"supports_es6":false,"country_code":"RU","language_code":"en","locale":"en_US","entry_data":{"PostPage":[{"graphql":{"shortcode_media":{"__typename":"GraphImage","id":"1968747493659350883","shortcode":"BtSZWokAZdj","dimensions":{"height":640,"width":640},"gating_info":null,"media_preview":"ACoq5miitSxxIGTHPXPGcd8ZFAGXRXSSWypFsAAZ/lzjpn/Csm5sjAu7Ib8MUAUaKU0lABVq0lMUqsPUA/Q8VVpynBB9CKAOtuOFB9CD+uP5Gq19HuiOPTP5Ul1exhdgy7kdF7fU/wCGatJiRPqv5ZFIZybnP4UynOpUlT1HFNpiClDFeRSUUATLcSJ904+lPF5MvR2H41WooAc7lzuY5J702iigD//Z","display_url":"https://instagram.fhel3-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/68311f4b09669fd75609e9fcabbf1ae0/5D0517DE/t51.2885-15/e35/49907137_294327238101721_6745007497573009307_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fhel3-1.fna.fbcdn.net","display_resources":[{"src":"https://instagram.fhel3-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/68311f4b09669fd75609e9fcabbf1ae0/5D0517DE/t51.2885-15/e35/49907137_294327238101721_6745007497573009307_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fhel3-1.fna.fbcdn.net","config_width":640,"config_height":640},{"src":"https://instagram.fhel3-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/68311f4b09669fd75609e9fcabbf1ae0/5D0517DE/t51.2885-15/e35/49907137_294327238101721_6745007497573009307_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fhel3-1.fna.fbcdn.net","config_width":750,"config_height":750},{"src":"https://instagram.fhel3-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/68311f4b09669fd75609e9fcabbf1ae0/5D0517DE/t51.2885-15/e35/49907137_294327238101721_6745007497573009307_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fhel3-1.fna.fbcdn.net","config_width":1080,"config_height":1080}],"accessibility_caption":"Image may contain: one or more people and closeup","is_video":false,"should_log_client_event":false,"tracking_token":"eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjo1LCJwYXlsb2FkIjp7ImlzX2FuYWx5dGljc190cmFja2VkIjp0cnVlLCJ1dWlkIjoiN2Q1Yjg2NmY5OGIwNDVhNWIxMmRhNjEwZTA3NDY1MmYxOTY4NzQ3NDkzNjU5MzUwODgzIn0sInNpZ25hdHVyZSI6IiJ9","edge_media_to_tagged_user":{"edges":[]},"edge_media_to_caption":{"edges":[{"node":{"text":"\u2022\nScars show your story. \nYour pain. \nYour hate.\nYour sadness and despair. \nThey make you who you are, and one of a kind with every different mark. \nSome stay, some go.\nSome brighter, some lighter.\nSome bigger, some smaller.\nSome deeper, some one the surface. \nBut they are really all the same, you see?\nThey are all scars, just telling different points of our life, our story. \nOur souvenir throughout our whole life, that shows us how much we've grown. \nHow much we have overcome. How strong we've become.\nHow brave and courageous we've become from the hardest and darkest times of our life. \u2022\n\u2022\n\u2022\n\u2022\n#poem #cuts #selfharm #tatoo #dark #pain #sad #lonely #anxiety #depressed"}}]},"caption_is_edited":true,"has_ranked_comments":false,"edge_media_to_comment":{"count":1,"page_info":{"has_next_page":false,"end_cursor":null},"edges":[]},"comments_disabled":false,"taken_at_timestamp":1548913011,"edge_media_preview_like":{"count":17,"edges":[]},"edge_media_to_sponsor_user":{"edges":[]},"location":null,"viewer_has_liked":false,"viewer_has_saved":false,"viewer_has_saved_to_collection":false,"viewer_in_photo_of_you":false,"viewer_can_reshare":true,"owner":{"id":"10173498181","is_verified":false,"profile_pic_url":"https://instagram.fhel3-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/9a17134e8d0a36efec53f1da5cac1f38/5D14BC0F/t51.2885-19/s150x150/47690762_475199173011446_4764198224049209344_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fhel3-1.fna.fbcdn.net","username":"devils..tea.","blocked_by_viewer":false,"followed_by_viewer":false,"full_name":"depressed\ud83e\udd40","has_blocked_viewer":false,"is_private":false,"is_unpublished":false,"requested_by_viewer":false}......
'''

r = re.compile(r'username":"(.*)(?=","blocked)')
print(r.findall(data))
```